# xml is not generated properly from XSD(only first element gets generated)

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd

I have an xsd which has 3 elemnets but, when i try to create xml from that xsd through eclipse juno, it generates xml structure only for the first element from the xsd.

My xsd has complex element which imports another xsd file.

Procedure what i follow for xml generation from eclipse is

1. right click on xsd.
2. go to generate option.
3. select xml file.

Kindly help me in resolving this issue, any help is greatly appreciated ...

**EDIT:**

**XSD :**

```
<element name="AddImageRequest" type="tns:AddImageRequest" />
<element name="AddImageResponse" type="tns:AddImageResponse" />
<element name="UpdateImageRequest" type="tns:UpdateImageRequest" />
```

**GENERATED XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:AddImageRequest xmlns:tns="http://com.cts.rewards/RewardsTypes/" xmlns:tns1="http://com.cts.rewards/BaseTypes/" xmlns:tns2="http://com.cts.rewards/CommonTypes/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://com.cts.rewards/RewardsTypes/ RewardsTypes.xsd ">
  <tla>tla</tla>
  <Image>
    <tns1:imageId>0</tns1:imageId>
    <tns1:imageLable>tns1:imageLable</tns1:imageLable>
    <tns1:image>
      <tns1:Image>MA==</tns1:Image>
    </tns1:image>
  </Image>
</tns:AddImageRequest>
```

Comment: I hope you know that XML documents can only have one root element. Can you provide more info on what options you selected on the second New XML File wizard page? Can you provide relevant section of the XSD and generated XML file and point us at a line where and how your expectations differ from what Eclipse generates?

Comment: @halfbit I have added a portion of my XSD elements and the generated xml for your refernce ..